# Math about Geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a geometric series, the sum of $1^{st}$ term $+$ $2^{nd}$ term $+$ $3^{rd}$ term $= 38$, 
the sum of $2^{nd}$ term $+ 4^{th}$ term $=  17 \frac{1}{3}$; 
how to calculate the common ratio? ( it is for sure the answer is $r= \frac{2}{3}$ and the first term $= 18$)

Comment: If we consider $\frac{a}{r^6}, \frac{a}{r^2},ar^2,ar^6,$, then we get $57r^{12}-26r^8+31r^4-26=0$, which I can not solve ; If we consider $\frac{a}{r^3}, \frac{a}{r},ar,ar^3,$, then we get $57r^{8}-26r^2+31r^4-26=0$, which I can not solve ;

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If your series is geometric with common ratio $r$ and first value $a$... then the terms of the sequence look like $a, ar, ar^{2}, ar^{3},...$.  Write out two equations in those two unknowns ($a$ and $r$) and solve.

The equations come out to be $a+ar+ar^2=38$ and $ar+ar^3=17+1/3$.

Answer (score 2):

$$a(1+r+r^2) = 38\\ar+ar^3 = \frac{52}3 $$ eliminating $a$ leaves us with 
$$\frac{1+r+r^2}{r+r^3} = \frac{57}{26}.$$ this can be rewritten as $$ 0=57r^3-26r^2+31r-26 = (3r-2)(19r^2+4r+13).$$ the quadratic equation $19r^2 + 4r+13=0 $ has no real roots, therefore $$r = \frac23, a = 18.  $$

Comment: How did you factor without solving ? Just curious. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, knowing the answer made it a little bit easier to factor.

Comment: ;Hahaha ! Knowing the answer !!

Comment: I use microsoft exel to solve the series, but that is not math way.

Answer (score 2):

TravisJ gave you the answer using definitions. The equations being $$a+ar+ar^2=38$$ $$ar+ar^3=17+\frac13=\frac{52}3$$ write the ratio to get $$\frac{a+ar+ar^2 }{ar+ar^3}=\frac{1+r+r^2 }{r+r^3}=\frac{57}{26}$$ Reduce to same denominator, simplify and you arrive to $$f(r)=57 r^3-26 r^2+31 r-26=0$$ which is a cubic equation which can be solved using radicals by Cardano method. But, without using it, what we can notice is that $$f'(r)=171 r^2-52 r+31$$ does not show any real root (negative discriminant); so, $f(r)$ is an increasing function.

By inspection, $f(0)=-26$ and $f(1)=36$; so the root is $0<r <1$. Inspection could be refined since $f(\frac12)=-\frac{79}8$ and $f(\frac34)=\frac{427}{64}$; so the root is $\frac12<r <\frac34$.

At this point, you could use Newton method starting in the middle of the last interval $x_0=\frac58$; the first iterate ise $$x_1=\frac{3727}{5572}\approx 0.66888$$ and the next is $x_2\approx 0.666673$; the solution looks to be $\frac23$ and it is easy to check that this is the solution.

Knowing $r$, use any of the two initial equations to get $a$.